# Trying to get object of non-object. (Laravel)

Tags: php, object, laravel-5

I'm confused here. I've passed

```
$grade=Grade::all()->whereLoose('id',$gid);
```

from my controller.
When I access it in my view like:

```
@foreach($grade as $grade)

{{$grade->grade_name}}


@endforeach
```

It works fine. But when i try to use it again in my table:

```
@foreach($grade as $grade)


<tr class="success">
    <td></td>
    <td><b>Balance</b></td>
    <td>{{$grade->fee_status}}</td>


@endforeach
```

It just throws Trying to get object of non object. What's the problem here? Can anyone help me?

Comment: try to dd($grade); And check the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reassigning `$grade` in your loop. It is now a single model. When you try to now iterate that you are iterating a single model which is not what you want to do (that will iterate the public properties of the object).

This will avoid that issue:

```
$grades = Grade::all()->whereLoose('id',$gid);

// different name for the variable for the current iteration
@foreach ($grades as $grade)
    ...
@endforeach

@foreach ($grades as $grade)
    ...
@endforeach
```

Watch the naming of variables.

On a side note, I am not sure why you are getting all the grades to just find the one with 'id' equal to `$gid`. If the `id` field is unique there should only be one and you wouldn't need to retrieve a collection.

```
$grade = Grade::find($gid);
```